# Assessing risk for UK visa refusal

Tags: visas, uk, tunisian-citizens

I'd like to visit the UK for 7 days (Standard Visa/Tourism):

1. I work online (freelance) and have irregular income.
2. I have incorporated a Company in my country (Tunisia) since 2011.
3. My company bank account has around £10,500. I have a International Debit Card with US$5,500 and around €4,000 in cash. My company bank account fluctuates irregularly but usually has a balance of 7,000-10,000 with irregular deposits/withdrawals. I can provide bank statements for all of the years.
4. I'm renting a property. Should I bring my rental contract?
5. I have a car.
6. In the last 10 years, I have travelled to multiple countries (Dubai (3 times), Turkey, Jordan, Hong Kong (2 times), Macau).
7. I speak fluent English with a slight accent.
8. I worked with a UK Company in the past (3 years ago).

Do I have a compelling case?

Comment: From the above it is not obvious you have any ties to your home country. Do you have any family in your country? Anyone needing care, like older parents? Anything at all, which would force you to return from UK and not overstay there and freelance online from UK?

Comment: Here in the UK, you cannot simply use a company bank account as your own (it would be considered fraudulent and can involve jail time) - therefore it might be difficult to use the company bank account and its funds as supporting evidence for your visa application unless you also provide evidence to the ECO that such use is legal and normal for your home country.

Comment: @GeorgeY. My parents live in another town. They have their own property.

Comment: @Moo The company in question is a legal structure for my freelance work. I'm the owner/manager of the said company.

Comment: @pnuts Sorry, I updated the post. Standard Visa/Tourism.

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: @AE Tunisia (born and living here)

Comment: @uk4visa yup, common setup here in the UK - but still illegal to use it as your personal bank account in the UK however, so you need to provide evidence that such use is legal in your country, and as such the funds in that bank account are 100"% yours to use as you see fit.  My earnings are done via my own company, and yet any movement in its bank account has to be 100% accounted for, I can't just go and buy this weeks groceries from that bank account even though myself and my wife are the sole owners and directors of the company.  I have to pay myself dividends and wages.

Comment: @Moo I just realized what you said (hit me in the head). So I think I was about to do a stupid mistake (and show the British customs my negligence about the law). How about turning this around and attending a tech conference (as well as getting an invitation letter from said conference). If conference is only for a few days (2-3 days) would it hurt if I apply for more days? (5-7 days). And again, how compelling is my case?

Comment: @uk4visa changing the purpose of your trip isn't going to change the criteria by which they judge your finances.

Comment: @uk4visa The point is that they won't treat funds in your company account as available to you, or proof of your income. It's too hard for them to figure out. Like, there maybe be £5000 comes in to your business every month. But if £4000 of that goes on to stock, and £500 on rent, then what's your income? Its too hard for them to figure out. Also, tax laws etc may mean you're not allowed to just take money out for personal use.

Answer (score 5):

Let's summarize it here, as comments started getting too long. Since you asked for the risk assessment, I'd focus on the risk factors only, so please accept my apology if the answer comes as overall negative - your case is way better than many others. However there are still concerns.

1. From the list above, and your follow-up comments it appears that you really have no significant ties with your home country. Those typically include work/business arrangements, having to take care of others, local responsibilities, and so on.

   **Work/business arrangements**: As far as I understand, the "freelance online" nature of your work lets you work from anywhere, including UK. Thus it becomes a concern, because shall you decide to overstay in UK, you'd have means to support yourself.

   **Having to take care of others**: No wife/no kids, and your parents don't need your care (likely since they live in a different city), it is not a tie.

   **Local responsibilities**: not clear if you have any from your list. Do you play in local sports team and have an event soon? Have a conference in your home city which you must attend? Running for a local election? Enrolling in local studies? Anything else which would *require* you to be back at specific date, is independently verifiable (so "friend wedding" is not good) and which couldn't be easily ignored?

   You see the pattern - you need to answer the question: if while in UK I'm offered a good job with the same salary, is there anything which would prevent me from taking this offer and staying in UK?
2. Financial concerns. You will likely need to include additional support documentation to prove that the "company bank account" is really your personal account. From the ECO's point of view it is not clear (they may think you're an employee of a company, and thus having access to account doesn't mean you've got a free hand using those money). Also in this case you'd probably need more documentation, such as company bylaws, balance sheet etc, to ensure that the company is in fact afloat (there are many having 100k at account, but owe much more). Here your situation is more difficult than for someone who's an employee.
3. You also need to have a clear answer to the question "why UK?" If this is a conference, does it match your work profile? Have you attended similar conferences locally, or nearby, in past? You'd have to convince them you're a genuine attendee, and didn't just Google something matching your dates to use it as an excuse. Especially if the conference is free.  Finally, it can become especially awkward if similar conferences are held locally in your own country.

Be sure to read the [Supporting Documents Guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) for what to include and what not to include.

Comment: In #2 s/own/owe/ (below min edit, but changes the meaning radically!)